# expected value of $x_{(1)} + x_{(4)} - x_{(2)} - x_{(3)}$

Tags: probability

> 4 players in a game, rolling dice. The one with the largest value and the one with the smallest value team up. The others team up as well. The winning team is the team with the biggest sum of the dice values. The payoff is the difference between the sums.

I think this is equivalent to the question that $X_i, i=1,2,3,4.$ are i.i.d random variable, how to calculate the expectation:
$$E[x_{(1)} + x_{(4)} - x_{(2)} - x_{(3)}].$$

**Solution:**

Since
$$E[x_{(1)} + x_{(4)} + x_{(2)} + x_{(3)}] = 4*3.5 = 14.$$

It is equivalent to calculate $E[x_{(1)}] + E[x_{(4)}],$ and we have

$$E[x_{(1)}] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^6P(x_{(1)}\geq k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^6P^3(x_i\geq k)$$
$$E[x_{(4)}] = \sum\limits_{k=1}^6P(x_{(4)}\geq k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^61 -P^3(x_i < k).$$
Therefore

$$E[x_{(1)}] + E[x_{(4)}] = 6 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^6P^3(x_i\geq k) -P^3(x_i < k).$$

Comment: Are $X_i$ sorted by number rolled? If so, they aren't iid. If not, the number you're trying to take the expected value of is more complicated than $X_1+X_4-X_2-X_3$.

Comment: Do you have tools for finding the expectation of $x_{(1)}$ and $x_{(4)}$? If so, you know the expectation of $x_{(1)} + x_{(4)} \color{blue}{+} x_{(2)} \color{blue}{+} x_{(3)}$ is simply the expectation of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4 \cdot 3.5$, so you could exploit that. If not, it's more challenging and brute force may be the most appealing option.

Comment: @Angelica The parentheses in the subscripts are common notation for order statistics, i.e. $x_{(1)} := \min\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$.

Comment: @MyMolecules equal numbers will have 0 difference.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery you are right, let me compute it.

Comment: You're probably in good shape from here, but one more thing you should consider: should the payoff be signed, or should it always be regarded as nonnegative regardless of which team wins it? If it's the latter case (and I fear it may be) then my outline may not be helpful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a fair $6$-sided die is thrown $4$ times with ordered outcomes $(x)_1\leq(x)_2\leq(x)_3\leq(x)_4$ then $(x)_1$ will have the same distribution as $7-(x)_4$ and $(x)_2$ will have the same distribution as $7-(x)_3$.

From this we conclude that:

$$\mathbb E(x)_1=7-\mathbb E(x)_4\text{ and }\mathbb E(x)_2=7-\mathbb E(x)_3$$

Consequently:$$\mathbb E[(x)_1+(x)_4-(x)_2-(x)_3]=7-7=0$$

Comment: here you use that factor x and 7-x have the same distribution, right?

Comment: Ah, I feel silly for not having seen this in my commenting above :) Nice one!

Comment: I use that $(x)_1$ (minimum) and $7-(x)_4$ ($7$ minus maximum) have the same distribution. Same story for $(x)_2$ and $7-(x)_3$ and based on the symmetry wrt $\frac72$.

Comment: @user6703592 I have to leave now. So for eventual further explanation I will be later at your disposal. Cheers.